# error al conectar sql con react

Tags: sql, reactjs, vscode

Quiero conectar mi App a sql, que he hecho con react para el front end y con Express para el back.

He creado una base de datos local y una tabla, pero no soy capaz de que me devuelva datos.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
    var sql = require('mssql');
    var config = {
        user: 'na',
        password: 'Ibgpruebas0',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'pruebas'
    };
    // conexion a bbdd
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        console.log('entra');
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from dbo.marcas', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(recordset);
            res.send(recordset);
        })
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor Express arrancado en el puerto ${port}`);
});
```

y me sale este error y no encuentro de donde viene.

```
>    { ConnectionError: Connection lost - socket hang up
        at ConnectionError (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
        at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1099:26)
        at Connection.socketEnd (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1118:12)
        at Socket.socket.on (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:977:14)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) message: 'Connection lost - socket hang up', code: 'ESOCKET' }
    { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
        at Request._query (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1399:37)
        at Request._query (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:546:11)
        at Request.query (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1335:12)
        at C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\server.js:18:17
        at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (C:\Users\iblancogonzalez\Desktop\New\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:287:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }
    undefined
```

He usado Visual Studio conde para programar.

Comment: ¿A qué Gestor de BBDD te estás conectando? ¿SQL Server? Échale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577248/node-js-mssql-tedius-connectionerror-failed-to-connect-to-localhost1433-conn